# A question about second fundamental form of Riemannian isometric embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-operators

I have got a question unsolved for some time. I do not know whether it is trivial or not:

**I omit a very important fact: The metric at point p is second-order flat, i.e. $d_p \phi(-,v) = 0$ and $d_p^2 \phi(-, v) = 0$. $d_p$ is differential of a function at p and $d_p^2$ is second differentiation **
(This is my first question and I would be more careful next time.)

Consider an isometric embedding $f: (U, \phi) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^4, \Phi)$, here $\phi$ is norm of 3-dim manifold $U$ and $\Phi$ is norm of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$. We define 2nd fundamental form as symmetric bilinear form $S(v, w) = <d_p^2 f(v,w), N>$. Here N is normal vector at point $f(p)$ of manifold $f(U)$. Here metric at point p is second-order flat.

Problem:

1. Is it true that: there exists $\tau \in \mathbb{R}^4 \setminus Im(d_p f)$ such that ${d_p}^2 f(v, w) = S(v, w) \tau$ for all $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ ?
2. Above question has an equivalent form: if 2nd fundamental form $S(v, w) = 0$ for linearly independent $v, w$, then $d_p^2 f(v, w) = 0$. Is it possible that $d_p^2 f(v, w)$ is nonzero tangent vector in the tangent space for some $v, w$ at a point of flat metric in 3-dim manifold? In this case this question can be proved incorrect.

Remark: The existence in problems 1, 2 can be proved when we embed 2-dim manifold into 3-dim Euclidean space, i.e. $f: (U, \phi) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^3, \Phi)$ and $U$ is 2-dim manifold.

More about notations:

1. $d_p^2 f(v, w) = d_p(d_p f(v))(w)$. Here $d_p f(v)$ is the linear map on tangent space, $d_p(d_p f(v))(w)$ is the second derivative of the map $f$, i.e. we move tangent vector $d_{γ(t)} f(v)$ along a curve $γ(t)$, with $γ(0) = p, γ'(0) = w$ in $U$ and take derivative of $t$, which gives a tangent vector $d_p(d_p f(v))(w)$.
2. Thanks to AntonPetrunin, above notation seems to not make sense. So I make an attempt on using a different notation: We first construct a chart on $r: R^3 \rightarrow U$ and this induces a map between charts $\tilde{f}: R^3 \rightarrow R^4$, so we just take second derivative of this map.

Comment: Why doesn’t the proof for the lower dimensional case work here?

Comment: Your definition does not make sense --- how do you «move» $d_{\gamma(t)}f(v)$ if $v$ is not longer tangent? So I suppose that you take usual second derivative, in this case curved coordinates on a hyperplane give you a counterexample.

Comment: @DeaneYang The reason lies in that in 2-dim manifold case, the tangent hyperplane of a point of unit circle of metric is only 1-dim and when we swap the order of second differentiation, we can get contradition. But in 3-dim manifold case, the tangent hyperplane is 2-dim so swapping the order cannot solve the problem.

Comment: @DeaneYang The proof of 2-dim case is that when $S(v, w) = <d_p^2 f(v, w), N> = 0$ combining with the flatness $d_{d_p f(v)} \Phi (d_p^2 f(v, w)) = 0$ (because $\phi$ is flat and f is isometric embedding), we can know that $d_p^2 f(v, w)$ lies in the tangent line of $d_p f(v)$ of unit circle of metric on the tangent space, we swap the order of differentiation and get that $d_{d_p f{w}} \Phi (d_p^2 f(v, w)) = 0$ which lies in the tangent line of $d_p f(w)$. So we can get contradiction when tangent lines of $d_p f(v)$ and $d_p f(w)$ are not parallel and when parallel we use -v instead of v.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Yes, it should just be usual second derivative. Would you like to give a little more detail? How to construct such curved coordinates on a hyperplane?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the metric is "second order flat"?

Comment: This question is really more suitable for math.stackexchange.com. If you move your question to there, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @threeautumn, if $(x,y,z)$ are standard coordinates, consider, say $(u,v,w)$ where $u=x$, $v=y+x^2$, $w=z+x^2+y^2$.

Comment: @DeaneYang I've copied the same question in stackexchange since I do not know how to move it. Thank you. I just got to know that stackexchange and mathoverflow are two different forums.

Comment: @DeaneYang Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497627/a-question-about-second-fundamental-form-of-riemannian-isometric-embedding